# converting text file to xml file in php

Tags: php, android, xml

i went through other stackoverflow topic such as "convert text file to xml file". but i tried those code for convert my text file to xml, but it seems nothing written in the xml file except "allproperty". My converting php file code is,

```
<?php $fp = fopen('some.txt', 'r');
$xml = new XMLWriter;
$xml->openURI('final.xml');
$xml->setIndent(true);
$xml->startElement('allproperty');
while ($line = fgetcsv($fp)) {
   if (count($line) < 4) continue;
   $xml->startElement('aproperty');
   $xml->writeElement('postcode', $line[0]);
   $xml->writeElement('price', $line[1]);
   $xml->writeElement('imagefilename', $line[2]); 
   $xml->writeElement('visits',$line[3]);
   $xml->endElement();
}
$xml->endElement();?>
```

if anybody can explain me what is wrong in the code??? and what is really happening by piece of this code?? and give me an alternative method to convert text file to xml using php??

Comment: What does your textfile look like?

Comment: just collection of words. Now i found that the problem is due to fgetcsv?? i think it will take only csv file words only.. please correct if i wrong..

Comment: Add an example for your 'some.txt', allow us to reproduce the problem and debug the source. XMLWriter is the right API for this however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the second and third parameter from the fgetcsv function. The second parameter is the size in characters(must be higher than maximum line lenght or 0 for endless line lenght -> is slower) and the third is the seperator (in your case a space " ").